# How to write optional in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I need to implement some rules by Prolog

ex:

`S ---> A,[b],{c}.`

Where:

[b] could happen once or none like 0 or 1 time

{c} could happen 0,1,2,...times

How can i write it?

***Edit:***

I used this:

```
:- op(700,xfx,--->).
s ---> [vp].
s ---> [vp,conj,vp].
s ---> [vp,conj,np].
vp ---> [feal_amr],
        ([mfoal_beh];[]),
        ([mfoal_beh];[]),
        ([bdl];[]),
        [sefa_optional],
        ([hal];[]),
        ([shbh_gomla];[]),
        ([mfoal_motlk];[]).
```

It gives me an error "Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2"

in the comma in this line "vp ---> [feal_amr], ..."

***Edit***

I use "--->" because i have this

```
parse_topdown(Category,String,Reststring,[Category|Subtrees]) :-
        Category ---> RHS,
        matches(RHS,String,Reststring,Subtrees).
```

And "-->" gives an error with the operator ":-"?!!

***this is my code for an*** [Arabic Parser Code](https://www.yousendit.com/download/WUJZblFPdzh3TGhESjlVag)

**I'm sorry for inconvenience but i am not an expert in Prolog**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your description

```
s --> [a], ([b] ; []), c_1.
c_1 --> [c], c_1 ; [].
```

some test pattern:

```
?- phrase(s, [a,b,c,c,c]).
true

?- phrase(s, [a]).
true
```

**edit**

about your code: you should use `-->`. Why you declare `--->` (and not define it) ? That way you should write *your own* analyzer, you're *not* using DCG.

Note that [vp,conj,vp] it's a list of **terminals**,

Not sure about feal_amr,mfoal_beh, etc etc, but vp it's surely a **nonterminal** (it's rewritten).

Then I think you should write

```
s --> vp.
s --> vp,conj,vp.
s --> vp,conj,np.

vp -->
  [feal_amr],
  ([mfoal_beh];[]),
  ([mfoal_beh];[]),
  ([bdl];[]),
  [sefa_optional],
  ([hal];[]),
  ([shbh_gomla];[]),
  ([mfoal_motlk];[]).

% I hypotesize it's a comma.
conj --> [','].
```

**edit** as noted in comments, you are *not* using DCG, but your own interpreter. I tested it with a minimal example

```
:- op(700,xfx,--->).

s ---> [name,verb,names].

names ---> [name, conj, names].
names ---> [name].
names ---> [].

lex(anne, name).
lex(bob, name).
lex(charlie, name).

lex(call, verb).
lex(and, conj).

parse_topdown(Category,[Word|Reststring],Reststring,[Category,Word]) :-
        lex(Word,Category).

parse_topdown(Category,String,Reststring,[Category|Subtrees]) :-
        Category ---> RHS,
        matches(RHS,String,Reststring,Subtrees).

matches([],String,String,[]).
matches([Category|Categories],String,RestString,[Subtree|Subtrees]) :-
        parse_topdown(Category,String,String1,Subtree),
        matches(Categories,String1,RestString,Subtrees).
```

and this program accepts 0,1, or more names:

```
?- parse_topdown(s,[anne,call,bob,and,charlie],R,P).
R = [],
P = [s, [name, anne], [verb, call], [names, [name, bob], [conj, and], [names|...]]] ;
R = [charlie],
P = [s, [name, anne], [verb, call], [names, [name, bob], [conj, and], [names]]] ;
R = [and, charlie],
P = [s, [name, anne], [verb, call], [names, [name, bob]]] ;
R = [bob, and, charlie],
P = [s, [name, anne], [verb, call], [names]] ;
false.
```

Note I leave R free, to examine partial matches. Coming back to your original question, you can see how the nonterminal `names` accepts 0,1,or many (separed by `and`) values.

Note that such interpreter will be very slow on any substantial input. I'd advise you to rewrite your grammar using DCG.

Comment: when i use it in my code it gives me an error "Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2"

Comment: thanks for your reply, forget about 'conj' i only put a part of the code.. i'm sorry
And about '--->' i use it cuz i have this:
`parse_topdown(Category,String,Reststring,[Category|Subtrees]) :-
  Category ---> RHS,
  matches(RHS,String,Reststring,Subtrees).`
so if i use "-->" instead of "--->" with the operator ":-" it gives an error
I'm sorry for being inconvenient but i'm not an expert in Prolog :(

Comment: I put a link for the code, could you please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: My original answer not is appropriate. I can see that ---> is interpreted by parse_topdown. Then you should try a *minimal* grammar that accepts 0,1,.. occurrences using that formalism. I'll try, but I by no means sure I'll succeed...

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably want to lower-case S and A; Prolog uses initial caps for variable names.

One way to allow 'b' to occur once or not at all is to write something like this:

```
s --> a, b_optional, {c}.

b_optional --> [b].
b_optional --> [].
```

There is also syntax for writing the two rules for b_optional as a single rule, if you prefer; consult the chapter on definite clause grammars in your favorite Prolog text.

I don't know what you mean by c happening 0, 1, 2, ... times, so I don't think I can help you there.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
About {c} .. i meant that it could be only (a,b) or (a,b,c) or (a,b,c,c) or (a,b,c,c,c) ... and so on

Comment: one question plz, what if i have s-->a,b,c where b, c are optional which could anyone of them come once or none .. how could i present it?
will i write 
s-->a,b_optional,c_optional.
b_optional-->[b].
b_optional-->[].
c_optional-->[c].
c_optional-->[].
or what?

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your use of [] and {}.  I guess now you were using `[b]` to mean 'optional b' and `{c}` to mean 'optional repeatable c'.  The confusion arises because square brackets and curly braces both have meaning in definite-clause grammars; in a DCG, `{c}` inserts a call to the predicate `c` at that point in the grammar rule, which succeeds if and only if `c` succeeds and matches nothing in the input.